# Syntax Error on Join Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

Working on my program I cam across an error I can't figure out. It happens when I try to extract the data from a database into a table. I can get it to extract properly from a single table, the problem is I have to use two tables. Which I am pretty sure means I need a join. However I get the error in the title when I try to load the page the table is on.

Code:

```
AccessDataSource theSource = PData;
theSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT Membership.idMembership, Membership.role, Users.lastname" 
        +"FROM Membership "
        +"INNER JOIN Users" 
        +"ON Membership.idUser = Users.idUsers;";
        try
        {
            DataView dv = (DataView)theSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

            TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
            TableHeaderCell ID = new TableHeaderCell();
            TableHeaderCell Role = new TableHeaderCell();
            TableHeaderCell User = new TableHeaderCell();
            ID.Text = "MemberID";
            Role.Text = "Role";
            User.Text = "User";
            thr.Cells.Add(ID);
            thr.Cells.Add(Role);
            thr.Cells.Add(User);
            tblNames.Rows.Add(thr);

            foreach (DataRowView aRow in dv)
            {
                String id = (String)aRow["Membership.idMembership"].ToString();
                String role = (String)aRow["Membership.role"];
                String user = (String)aRow["Users.lastname"].ToString();
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                TableCell one = new TableCell();
                TableCell two = new TableCell();
                TableCell three = new TableCell();
                one.Text = id;
                one.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                two.Text = role;
                two.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                three.Text = user;
                three.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                tr.Cells.Add(one);
                tr.Cells.Add(two);
                tr.Cells.Add(three);
                tblNames.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Please advise

Comment: Add a space after `INNER JOIN Users`

Comment: In the future, whenever you “get the error”, please remember to show us the error message.

Comment: I think everybody's made this mistake at one point in their lives...

Comment: @ElGavilan - Lord knows I have...

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```
"SELECT Membership.idMembership, Membership.role, Users.lastname"
+"FROM Membership "
+"INNER JOIN Users" 
+"ON Membership.idUser = Users.idUsers;";
```

will create this string:

```
SELECT Membership.idMembership, Membership.role, Users.lastnameFROM Membership INNER JOIN UsersON Membership.idUser = Users.idUsers;
```

You need to put a space after `Users` and `Users.lastname`:

```
"SELECT Membership.idMembership, Membership.role, Users.lastname "
+"FROM Membership "
+"INNER JOIN Users " 
+"ON Membership.idUser = Users.idUsers;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two spaces in your query:

```
theSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT Membership.idMembership, Membership.role, Users.lastname "  // added extra space here
    +"FROM Membership "
    +"INNER JOIN Users " // added extra space here
    +"ON Membership.idUser = Users.idUsers;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two spaces in your SQL command, one at the end of the SELECT statement, one at the end of the JOIN statement, so try:

```
theSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT Membership.idMembership, Membership.role, Users.lastname " 
    +"FROM Membership "
    +"INNER JOIN Users " 
    +"ON Membership.idUser = Users.idUsers";
```

You face the error because without spaces is not valid SQL query; you can simply check it in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers are missing spaces; they are also needed before the "FROM".

The correct answer is this (with *'s denoting where additional spaces should be placed):

```
theSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT Membership.idMembership, Membership.role, Users.lastname" 
        + "*FROM Membership "
        + "INNER JOIN Users" 
        + "*ON Membership.idUser = Users.idUsers;"
```